# Magento 2 Categorty page blank with following error

Tags: magento2, category-listing, blank-theme

Magento 2 Categorty page blank with following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface in /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(167): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(273): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Invento...', NULL, 'stockResolver', 'Amasty\\Shopby\\P...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Facto in /var/www/vhosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a di.xml reference to an implementation of Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface that is inside a module that is disabled.

Search your code base for Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface in di.xml to find exactly which one it is and enable that module.

You could also do bin/magento module:status and enable your modules one by one until it starts to work.

I also see in your error message that the error comes from Amasty\Shopby, so it could be that the Amasty is referencing to a class that either is disabled or do not exist anymore, you could try updating the Amasty module.

Comment: Thankd for the pointer but cant find Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface in the di.xml

Comment: Is there a way to rebuild the di.xml file from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Found the offending mod as mentioned in the error message
uninstalled amasty shopby, compiled site and re-indexed and now working fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on one project where all `Magento_Inventory*` were disabled. When we upgraded the core, new `Magento_Inventory*` modules got enabled by default which caused the error.

By doing a quick search on `etc/config.php`, I quickly found and disabled all those new modules and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all to replace some magento modules. The "amasty/shiprestriction" forced me to pick some modules out of the replace list:

```
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
```

After installing "amasty/xsearch" I got this error too, so i removed the following replace:

```
    "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
```

After that, the indexing process works again.
The reason is, that now the following preference is available:

```
    <preference for="Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface" type="Magento\InventorySales\Model\StockResolver"/>
```

The codeblock from "amasty/xsearch", which referenced the api-module:

```
<virtualType name="searchStockResolver" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Model\Di\Wrapper">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```